# How to convert CSV's to UTF-8 with PHP

Tags: php, csv, utf-8, character-encoding

I have looked all over the internet and i cannot find an answer.

I am scraping thousands of CSV's from a source out of my control. The CSV can be ANY character encoding. so i need to convert them all to UTF-8.

I have read online that if you convert utf-8 to utf-8 the data gets scrabbled, so what i am trying to do is detect the character encoding of the file and if its not utf-8 i want to convert it to utf-8 (i plan to use iconv).

I have tried everything on stack overflow (and other sites) but i cannot seem to get the current encoding of the file.

If i use

```
mb_detect_encoding(file_get_contents($csvPath), mb_detect_order(), TRUE);
```

or

```
mb_detect_encoding(file_get_contents($csvPath),'auto');
```

has anyone got any suggestions on how i can detect the encoding of the csv or have a better way that i can convert files without knowing the original encoding.

Comment: If you don't know the original encoding, the best you can do is guess. This is why it is important to store/know/communicate the encoding.

Comment: Damn, what would be your best advice for 'guessing'? guess the encoding, try convert, then read file to check if characters are jumbled if so try next encoding?

Comment: Also how do you know how programmes like bbedit or textwrangler detect encoding, because they seem to do it flawlessly

Comment: I'm not an encoding guru, and I'm not familiar with the `mb_` APIs. Hopefully someone who knows better than I will come along. Your question isn't exactly clear however. Does this code you've shown work? Is it mis-detecting any files?

Comment: Fair enough thanks for the input. I have read in multiple places that its hard to read the encoding of a file. :(

Comment: How are you acquiring the source files? If it's from a web server, there may be a content-encoding header present in the response  (that you may or may not be able to trust).

Comment: ah! good point i didn't think about that. It is coming from a web server. I guess the only choice is to trust it :/ ill give it a try and let you know how it goes, thanks

Comment: *"if you convert utf-8 to utf-8 the data gets scrabbled"* – No, you'd need to be doing something very wrong then. If you tell your computer to convert a piece of text from UTF-8 to UTF-8, it should simply do nothing, because the text is already in the desired encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Iv figured it out after hours of trial and error. forget mb_detect_encoding its useless.

to the shell instead and use iconv (installed by default on OSX and Linux).

```
$output = shell_exec("file --mime-encoding GBP_AUD_Week1.csv");
$output = str_replace("$csvPath: ", '', $output);
```

This gives the current file encoding

```
shell_exec(iconv -f $output -t utf-8 GBP_AUD_Week1.csv > GBP_AUD_Week1Converted.csv);
```

**Note:**
I tried to overwrite the file instead of creating a new one, but when i did this the file was blank and the encoding was binary.

Comment: This may still fail unpredictably… guessing an encoding correctly is fundamentally impossible. Files are just bags of bytes; text files (including CSV) are just bags of bytes which when interpreted in the right encodings happen to result in human readable text. Any bag of bytes can be interpreted in a number of encodings which will result in different text; whether this text is "correct" or not only a human can judge (even a statistical analyser could only give you a confidence rating at best).

Comment: thanks for the comment, i understand this already, however i dont really have much choice :( My programme scrapes thousands of CSV and opening them all up in something like text wrangler and saving them in new encoding isn't viable (the csv's can be up to 200MB). My issue is PHP cant do string comparisons on Unicode UTF-16 without me using regex to delete hidden characters. (also the CSV's could be any encoding, so my one bit of regex isnt enough).  After converting i am doing some checks on the data to make sure its readable. If you have any suggestions that my help me please let me know.

Comment: I'd try to use a statistical encoding detector (it tries several encodings, and of those which are not outright invalid, does a statistical analysis on the decoded text and checks if the characters seem to form proper words in a given language), followed by human inspection of the result, at least the results with low confidence score. No, I can't suggest any particular library for that, I try to avoid this kind of situation from the beginning. ;-)